# Blender Soft selection mode

Tags: selection-tools

How could that mode be actually used if it doesn't have any visual display of the active zones ( color gradient) ?

Answer (score 1):

At the end of the day, Blender isn't 3DS nor Maya and you will have to understand the different approaches each software has to do the same things, if you don't want to have a headache at every step.

One of the big difference is that 3DS wants you to prepare your tools settings first, then select, then apply the tool's effect on selection, while Blender wants you to select, open the tool and adapt it in real time until you are happy of what you get. This difference in approach is part of why it is more crucial to preview what you are doing beforehand in softwares likes 3DS while Blender wants to just make you do things more interactively.

I.E. If you want to move a bunch of vertices with proportional editing, you can enable proportional editing beforehand via the GUI or while using the Move operator using <kbd>O</kbd>. You see how things behave on the fly, and you can use your <kbd>[image: MW] MW</kbd> up/down to adjust the area of effect, and you <kbd>[image: LMB] LMB</kbd> to apply or <kbd>[image: RMB] RMB</kbd> to cancel.

Having a gradient preview has been requested a few times, like there:
[proportional editing, viewport visualization ⁠— Right-Click Select](https://blender.community/c/rightclickselect/MCbbbc/?sorting=hot)

But so far it hasn't been implemented.

Comment: Hi Lolock thanks for the answer! Yes I do understand the approach but you can't qualify that case as an approach thing..as what Blender offers is not enough to follow with your eys what happens to all the vertices that moved..it is a feature that is not well thought so it dosn't surve its purpose..they just need the gradient map so that feature becomes meaningless for modelers etc.

Comment: How could so many people use that feature with no issue if it was meaningless without a gradient preview?

Comment: they use it because they have nothing better to use..